# Find a approximate value of e^(-4) using Taylor series, so that error is less than 10^(-3)

Tags: taylor-expansion

So, the Taylor series for $e^x$ is $e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!}+ \ldots + \frac{x^n}{n!}$.
In this instance I have $x = -4$, so the series looks as follows:
$$1 - 4 + \frac{4^2}{2!} - \frac{4^3}{3!} + \ldots  + (-1)^n\frac{4^n}{n!}.$$

So what is the way I can find a value of the function with a error smaller than $10^{-3}$?

Comment: For a decreasing, alternating series, the absolute error is bounded by the first omitted term.  Now, here, the series doesn't start decreasing for a while, but eventually it is decreasing.

Comment: $ |e^{-4} - P(x)| < 10^{-3}$

Comment: For Taylor series of $f(x)$ around $0$ upto $x^n$ , the approximation error is given by $R_n(x) = \frac{M}{(n+1)!} |x|^n$ where $M$ is the maximum value of $n+1$ derivative of $f(z)$ for $0 < z <x$. So in this case, we have $R_n(x) = \frac{1}{(n+1)!} |x|^n$. So choose $n$ such that $R_n(-4) < 10^{-3}$ to get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have an alternating series.

As you know the error in alternating series is less than the absolute value of the next term.

Therefore you need to find $n$ such that $|4^n|/{n!}<0.001$
I found that for $n=15$ the error term is less than $0.001$ so you need to add up the first $14$ terms to satisfy the tolerance of $0.001$